# Corrupted zip file after sending it via ftp in command line (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp, zip

I am making a bat file to compress a file and then send it via ftp, everything works all right but the file after sending to the ftp sometimes is corrupted specially when its large and encrypted, the local zip file is OK. I checked on the internet and it says that it might be a problem with the transfer mode, but I set it to binary and the same problem.

```
@echo off

REM time format hhssmm

set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
REM echo hour=%hour%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
REM echo min=%min%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
REM echo secs=%secs%

REM date format yyyymmdd
set year=%date:~0,4%
REM echo year=%year%
set month=%date:~5,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
REM echo month=%month%
set day=%date:~8,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%
REM echo day=%day%

set pass="password"
Start 7za.exe a file_%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%.zip * -r -mx9 -p%pass% -mhe

set "file=file_%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%.zip"
REM set username = all
REM set userpass = 12345

echo debug> ftpcmd.dat
echo user all> ftpcmd.dat
echo 12345>> ftpcmd.dat
echo binary>> ftpcmd.dat
status
echo put %file%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat xx.xxx.xxx.xx
del ftpcmd.dat
pause
```

I am using 7-Zip command line executable, 7za.exe. to compress the file.
This is the outcome:

```
status
Connected to xx.xxx.xxx.xx.
220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.43 beta
220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
ftp> debug
Debugging On .
ftp> user all
---> USER all
331 Password required for all

---> PASS 12345
230 Logged on
ftp> binary
---> TYPE I
200 Type set to I
ftp> put file_20140205_093700.zip
---> PORT xx,xxx,xxx,xx,xx,x
200 Port command successful
---> STOR file_20140205_093700.zip
150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/file_20140205_093700.zip"
226 Successfully transferred "/file_20140205_093700.zip"
ftp: 179312 bytes sent in 0,00Seconds 179312000,00Kbytes/sec.
ftp> quit
---> QUIT
221 Goodbye
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Can you add as first line in your ftpcmd.dat `debug` and before your put statement `status` and let us know the outcome

Comment: You file is locally also 179312 bytes? How do you determine that the file is corrupted? Do you perform a GET?

Comment: This may be a problem with your ftp software as well. Try consulting the help documents the software provides.

Comment: I see now. When its corrupted the size is different in the ftp folder and I got this error "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged", but don't know why sometimes it works. What do you mean by perform a GET?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found the problem. The 7za.exe was still compressing when the file was sent to the ftp, just add START /WAIT after starting the exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I found the problem. The `7za.exe` was still compressing when the file was sent to the ftp, just add START /WAIT after starting the exe:

```
START /WAIT 7za.exe a file_%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%.zip * -r -mx9 -p%pass% -mhe
```

Here is the hole script after the changes with some improvements. It makes a zip file password protected and send it vie ftp. Yo can set the parameters in the command window or save it in the script.

You just need 7zip command line(7za.exe) in the same folder

```
@ECHO off

REM time format hhssmm
SET hour=%time:~0,2%
IF "%hour:~0,1%" == " " SET hour=0%hour:~1,1%
REM ECHO hour=%hour%
SET min=%time:~3,2%
IF "%min:~0,1%" == " " SET min=0%min:~1,1%
REM ECHO min=%min%
SET secs=%time:~6,2%
IF "%secs:~0,1%" == " " SET secs=0%secs:~1,1%
REM ECHO secs=%secs%

REM date format yyyymmdd (Adjust to local date format)
SET year=%date:~0,4%
REM ECHO year=%year%
SET month=%date:~5,2%
IF "%month:~0,1%" == " " SET month=0%month:~1,1%
REM ECHO month=%month%
SET day=%date:~8,2%
IF "%day:~0,1%" == " " SET day=0%day:~1,1%
REM ECHO day=%day%

REM set filename with current timestamp
SET filename=file_%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%.zip

REM to ask to set zip password
SET /p zippass=Set zip password:

REM to set the zip password instead of asking for it
REM SET zippass="p"

REM to ask for parameters
SET /p ftphost=Enter ftphost:
SET /p username=Enter user:
SET /p userpass=Enter password:

REM to save the parameters instead of asking for them
REM SET ftphost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
REM SET username=all
REM SET userpass=12345

SET encrypt_headers=
REM SET encrypt_headers=-mhe

START /wait 7za.exe a %filename% * -r -mx9 -p%zippass% %encrypt_headers% -x!7za.exe -x!zip_ftp.bat -x!zip_ftp_ask.bat
SET file=%filename%

@ECHO off
ECHO user %username%> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO %userpass%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO bin>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO put %file%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %ftphost%
DEL ftpcmd.dat
PAUSE
```