# FTP Script to move files from Suse server to ftp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp, suse

We need to move all the files from particular folder to ftp server.  We wrote a script but getting directory not found exception.  Below is the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='192.168.1.100'
USER='ramesh'
PASSWD='rameshftp'
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWD
cd /home/Ramesh
put *.zip
bye
EOF
```

Our requirement is to copy all the files which resides in some directory in Suse Linux Server and copy to FTP server. for eg: Copy all the contents from "/home/Ramesh" directory and put into ftp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one line with `ncftp`:

```
ncftpput -u username -p password ftp-host-name /path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir/*
```

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/ncftp for more info

Comment: I have made changes some changes in script that will zip a file and move to ftp but when i download a file from ftp the zip file will be corrupted.  Any idea about this issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572043/corrupted-zip-file-after-sending-it-via-ftp-in-command-line-bat